# Поиск и замена подстрок в строке

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! Есть цель не столько решить задачу, сколько понять принцип. Есть у нас к примеру строка :

```
String str = "One 1, Two1, Three, 1 Four 1";
```

нужно заменить все 1 на 2. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это лучше сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String new_str = str.replace ('1', '2');
```

Comment: Ясно, вроде бы просто. Так же хотелось бы спросить: в каких ситуациях стоит использовать regexp и , если не трудно, как?
Спасибо.

Comment: юзайте поиск хотя бы по этому сайту

Comment: регулярки стоит использовать только в крайних случаях, когда нужно произвести сложный анализ и модификацию строк, которые невозможно сделать другими методами. Регулярки работают довольно медленно и никогда нельзя гарантировать правильность их работы.

Comment: @burningsky, учтите в str **замена не происходит**, str.replace() **делает копию str с заменой символов**.

Понимание этого **крайене важно**. В Java содержимое строки **нельзя изменить**.

Comment: Для прямой редакции строк нужно использовать класс StringBuffer

Comment: StringBuffer, StringBuilder и String это **разные** классы, соответственно и их поведение разное. В вопросе был String.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию.